# Checking a data member of a derived class

Tags: c++, class, implementation, derived-class, datamember

My question is more of a conceptual/learning one that applies in this specific instance.  I'm doing an assignment, and I have a class called sensor, and a derived class called digitalSensor.  One of the data members of sensor is "functioning".  And, when I implement the print function for digitalSensor I need to print out a line based on whether the digital sensor is "functioning" or not.

essentially, I need to make an if statement in digitalSensor where it checks the value of "functioning".  But Xcode tells me that "functioning is a private member of sensor".  Since digitalSensor is derived from sensor, shouldn't it also have the "functioning" member variable?  How do I check it in my creation of the digitalSensor print function?

Here is my sensor.h file:

```
#ifndef __Program_6__sensor__
#define __Program_6__sensor__

#include <iostream>

class sensor {
    char* SensorName;
    float energyDraw;
    int functioning;
    int onoff;

public:
    sensor(char*n, float pc);
    virtual void print();

    void setOK(int K);
    int getOK();
    void setOnOff(int n);
    int getOnOff();
};
//---------
class digitalSensor : public sensor {
    int reading;

public:
    digitalSensor(char*n, float pc);
    virtual void print();
    void setCurrentReading(int r);
    int getCurrentReading();
};

class analogSensor : public sensor {
    int Reading;
    int minRead;
    int maxRead;

public:
    analogSensor(char *n, float pc, int mm, int mx);
    virtual void print();
    void setCurrentReading(int r);
    int getCurrentReading();
};


#endif /* defined(__Program_6__sensor__) */
```

And here is my sensor.cpp file, my work on the print function is at the bottom:

```
#include "sensor.h"
#include "definitions.h"
using namespace std;

//--------SENSOR CLASS------------//
sensor::sensor(char *n, float pc) {

    SensorName = (char*)malloc(strlen(n)+1);
    energyDraw = pc;
    functioning = WORKING;
    onoff = OFF;
}
void sensor::print() {
    cout << "     Sensor: " << SensorName;
    cout << "   Power Consumption: " << energyDraw;
    if (functioning == WORKING) {
        cout << "\nSensor is functioning correctly\n";

        if (onoff == ON) {
        cout << "Sensor is On";
    }
        if (onoff == OFF) {
        cout << "Sensor is Off";
    }

    }
    if (functioning == NOTWORKING) {
        cout << "Sensor is not functioning correctly";
    }
    }
void sensor::setOK(int k) {
    functioning = k;
}
int sensor::getOK() {
    return functioning;
}
void sensor::setOnOff(int n) {
    onoff = n;
}
int sensor::getOnOff() {
    return onoff;
}
//---------------------------------//

//*********DIGITAL SENSOR**********//

digitalSensor::digitalSensor(char *n, float pc) : sensor(n, pc){
    reading = OFF;

}
void digitalSensor::print() {
    sensor::print();
    if (functioning == WORKING && onoff == ON) {
        cout << "Current sensor reading is: " << reading;
    }
    if (digitalSensor.functioning == WORKING && digitalSensor.onoff == OFF) {
        cout << "Current reading not available";
    }
}
```

The error is two lines after "void digitalSensor::print()" there at the end.

thanks for any help you all can give!  I'll make sure to reciprocate and answer newbie questions too someday once I learn this stuff!

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++, use `new`.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two underscores (`__Program_6__sensor__`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: `digitalSensor` **does** have a data member named `functioning`. The error message is telling you that the data member is private in the base, so it can't be **accessed** from the derived class. If it didn't have the data member the error message would say that there is no such data member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ the default visibility for `class` members is `private`, which means that fields and methods are not accessible from the outside, *not even from subclasses*. The solution is marking the concerned fields as `protected` (same as `private`, but accessible from subclass):

```
class sensor {
protected:
    char* SensorName;
    float energyDraw;
    int functioning;
    int onoff;

public:
    sensor(char*n, float pc);
    virtual void print();

    void setOK(int K);
    int getOK();
    void setOnOff(int n);
    int getOnOff();
};
```